# Custom List Filter - update list view only on second button click

Tags: list, list-view, filter

What I try to do is making a simple list filter tool for SharePoint 2010 lists.

**What I have so far:** I made a VisualWebPart (VWP) named "ListFilter", which should update the view of the list (see code below). I add the VWP to the already existing WebPartPage of a List in SharePoint.

**The problem:** After the first button click (`btnSearchButton_Click`), the list view does not update, after the second click, it does update. I already tried (as I read about page lifecycle) to put the `filterList(String sw)` into `Page_Load` or `Page_Init`, but without success. Maybe the cause of this is that the list renders again on postback (but as far as I know I can't influence that?!?!)

**My goal:** Update the list view on the first click on the button.

---

My Code for VWP "ListFilter":

**ListFilterUserControl.ascx:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxSearchWord" runat="server" ToolTip="Suchwort eingeben" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchButton" runat="server" Text="Suche" ToolTip="Suche starten" onclick="btnSearchButton_Click" />
```

**ListFilterUserControl.ascx.cs (code behind):**

```
// Class Variables:
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
String mySearchWord;
SPList list;
SPView view;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

protected void btnSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mySearchWord = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.tbxSearchWord.Text) == false) ? this.tbxSearchWord.Text.ToString() : "No searchword entered";
        filterList(this.mySearchWord);
    }

public void filterList(String sw)
    {
        list = currentWeb.Lists["Listname"];
        view = list.Views[list.GetUncustomizedViewByBaseViewId(1).Title.ToString()];
        String query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='fieldName'/><Value Type='Text'>" + sw + "</Value></Contains></Where>";
        view.Query = query;
        currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        view.Update();
        currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

---

Mayby someone could point me to the right direction ... I'm not that experienced in programming C# / .Net. Thank you very much in advance!

---

---

***EDIT***

I added `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());` to the `filterList(String sw)`-Method which reloads the page after the button click. It works now as intended, but I think it's not really a nice solution. If someone knows something better, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

You can use existing Filter Web Part available OOB for this purpose. Have a look at 
[Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx)

However if you wish to do with Visual Web Part [as sometimes the OOB isn't enough], on btnSubmit_click redirect the page to the same page with Query String of your textbox value, something like:

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.tbxSearchWord.Text))
   Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "[pageUrl].aspx?filter=" + this.tbxSearchWord.Text.Trim());
```

Now edit your page in SharePoint Designer - add a filter to the List View with a parameter from Query String, parameter name "filter" !

For preserving the value of filter text on redirect, you can do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["filter"]))
            {
                this.tbxSearchWord.Text = Request.QueryString["filter"];
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Arsalan,
thanks for your answer. I'll give that a try, but in fact I want to create a reusable list filter which can be used for all lists in our company network (the code I posted was just a simplified version to show what I mean). I'm not sure if your solution would work for that purpose. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: I guess that is not the problem, as far as you define the Filters and Query String Parameters in your List View... It should work for all the list views..